# Integrating Angular.js SPA with .NET

Tags: .net, angularjs, authentication, iis, single-sign-on

My team and I are trying to integrate an Angular.js SPA with our companies SSO libraries. Those libraries are available in .NET and Java - our team is a .NET shop. These libraries expose API that allow developers to get information about who is logged in, etc. We're using, and love, Yeoman to develop the SPA.

Is there a way to wrap the SPA application around the .NET SSO libraries other than integrating the SPA into a Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the library on server side. It is server side data that needs to be protected. Implement SSO on whatever respods to your REST calls (I guess). Of course you can try to protect your JS code as well - still server side. Technically technology used on front end does not matter since auth framework works on HTTP level.